# Matrices, How to solve for x?

Tags: matrices

Not sure how to do this problem.

[image: Here is an example of the problem]

How do I do it? Do I divide each side by 3? Do I multiply the matrices on the left by 3?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a $2$ by $2$ matrix, you can solve this equation component by component. For example, in the top left entry, you have the equation $ 8 - 3a = 7$, where $a$ is the top left entry of $X$. Can you do the rest?